# Animate component when change route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I would like to achieve a behavior such as this:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/videos/layout-transition.gif

I want to have an image in one component (e.g. product card), and when i'm clicking on that component, it will switch route (e.g. product page) but will keep the same component just resize it to be bigger.

Is it possible using React DOM?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful for you to make an attempt and provide the code in your question. Please see [ask] for more information.

Comment: [This](https://dev.to/dutzi/animating-route-transitions-using-react-router-5blp) might help to start (post about animation between routes)